# Is the major difference between RDF and Labelled Property Graph?

Tags: neo4j, rdf

For example, Barack Obama, in Labelled Property Graph, the birth date (1965) would be modeled as a Property of the entity BarackObama, without using a relation. But in RDF, i.e. freebase, BarackObama is linked through a relationship (birth_date) to a value '1965'. In these two cases, the former involves only one entity without relationship, but the latter, two entities are involved, "BarackObama" and "1965" with a relationship.

Is this the major difference?

Comment: [RDF Triple Stores vs. Labeled Property Graphs: What's the Difference](https://dzone.com/articles/rdf-triple-stores-vs-labeled-property-graphs-whats) (slightly biased). See also [Reification is red gerring](http://www.snee.com/bobdc.blog/2018/04/reification-is-a-red-herring.html) and [An introduction to Graph Data Management](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1801.00036.pdf)

Comment: I read that. That talks a lot. What about my question above? Is that a major difference in the example?

Comment: No. In LPG, birth year might be modeled as a node, as well as a property value. In RDF, birth year might be modeled as a literal, as well as an URI.

Comment: Yes, that's possible. But the key difference is that in RDF, there is no concept of 'attribute' on a node, and all attributes (properties) have to be linked by a relationship, and the attribute can be a literal value, or an object. But in LPG, a node can be no any links, but only attributes. A LPG node is more like an Object in  Java or C++, or any other object-oriented programming language.

Comment: HTH: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51840976/7879193, esp. the link to the mapping description.