# How to import .rdf file in Neo4j database?

Tags: neo4j, rdf, dgraph

I have a .rdf file which I was used for Dgraph in order to import the data and the subsequently queries in order to get the relations in the Dgraph Ratel UI.

Now I need to include in my web application for which Dgraph doesn't have support ([link](https://github.com/dgraph-io/dgraph/issues/2523)). Hence I started looking for Neo4j.

Can anyone please help out how to import .rdf file in Neo4j if not what's the workaround.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Labeled property graph (LPG) and RDF graph are different graph data models, see:

- [RDF Triple Stores vs. Labeled Property Graphs: What's the Difference?](https://dzone.com/articles/rdf-triple-stores-vs-labeled-property-graphs-whats) by Jesus Barrasa
- [Reification is red herring](http://www.snee.com/bobdc.blog/2018/04/reification-is-a-red-herring.html) by Bob DuCharme

Neo4j supports LPG data model only. However, there is the [**neosemantics**](https://github.com/jbarrasa/neosemantics) Neo4j plugin.
After installation, say:

```
CALL semantics.importRDF(<RDF_file_path>, <RDF_serialization_format>)
```

The mapping from RDF to LPG is described [here](https://jbarrasa.com/2016/06/07/importing-rdf-data-into-neo4j/).

---

I'd suggest you to use a proper *triplestore* for RDF data.

Comment: Thanks a lot, will try and if got stuck will let you know.